# Parse - avoid sharing information in specific column of a class

Tags: parse-platform

I've got a question about the best way to allow user's information to be visible between users in certain situations.
I have certain columns in User class which are private to the user.
In some activity i'm pointing to user object as 'postedBy' or something else,In this case the entire data regarding user is getting shared.

My question is how to restrict user to get some columns in User class??

Answer (score 0):

usually if you want to restrict an access in parse it should be done via ACL. In ACL you can create role for users who can read/write to the class.
ACL are executed on a class level and not on a column level. In order to expose part of the fields i think you have 2 options:

1. Create one to one realtionship from your User class to another Class. the second class will contain all columns that not all users can see and for this class create ACL's with the users/roles that can view this data and when you will execute your query only the users with sufficient permissions will be able to get this data
2. The second option is when you want to avoid relationships here you can use the **select** option under query. Select allows you to select specific fields of the class and the query will return only the fields that you specified under the select. here is a code snippet from parse docs which explain how to use select (in JS):

```js
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.select("score", "playerName");
    query.find().then(function(results) {
      // each of results will only have the selected fields available.
    });
```

Hope its clear now :)